# Preserving the order of status bar icons between restarts

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I know I can reorder them manually using Command key and mouse drag and drop, but this order is not preserved between the restarts. The order seems to be according to the order the apps managed to load on system start, but this isn't always the same.

Is there any way to preserve the order of icons on the macOS menu bar between restarts of the system?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a bug - after a few months since opening it on Apple Feedback (while macOS 11 was in Beta 3 I think) I finally got reply this was fixed, and indeed so far in macOS 11.1 (build 20C69) everything seems to be back in order. Thank you to everyone who participated in this thread!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/), which keeps the order of the icons fixed (and does much more). It's a paid software, but it has a free trial and is available in [Setapp](https://setapp.com/).

Comment: Note, in macOS Big Sur, the clock/notification centre and control centre menu items are permanently fixed respectively (right to left) in the menu bar and can’t be reordered or hidden by Bartender 4.